# Unable to locate my business in Google Places API

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I'm currently attempting to create a link for my customers to leave a Google review. I have attempted to find my business via Places API but nothing shows up. My business is verified on Google. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you could at least drop something so we can help? like the name of your business, address, some of the code

Comment: Apologies. My business is David Grant Simpson Photography.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have created API key for the google place api,

Now just modify below link accordingly, then hopefully it will give the desired result.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?types=establishment&input=&key=

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I did this and got the following message:

Comment: {
   "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: You need an API key for running the google maps apis, or you can share the below link with place id , given in the answer above.                                                                                  https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=<Place id>

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate everything. Cheers, David

Answer (score 0):

If you created your business as Service Area Business, it won't show up in Places API web service. In order to find place ID for SABs you have to use the place ID finder of Google My Business that is located at

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/faq#how-to-find-placeid

When I search the 'David Grant Simpson Photography' in this place ID finder I get the place ID `ChIJaUxp_09GiEgRpgCejm52hQg` as shown in my screenshot

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks so much for helping me out mate. It's really appreciated.